# Became out of reign

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, lateral-thinking

I created this puzzle today:

THEPE:MON:NOTEA (US)

…. … ..h

The puzzle above wants you to fill in the blanks

Edit: I just made it maybe a little easier to work out

Hint:

> Treat the first half of the puzzle like a rebus

Big Hint:

> what could the last 4 letters be referring to?

Hint

> J___

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the answer

> July the 4th??

> Otea is a dance from Tahiti

> Mon short for Monday which is a day so using the rebus clue I think it is pointing at: day in‘thependance’. (This is a common rebus trick).

> This gives two clues: day and independence

and

> along with the US clue in points to the US day of independence.

Comment: Hey Tom welcome to PSE. Bravo you got the right answer!!